# Minimalistic telnet prompt wait time

Tags: c#

I apologize if this is a remedial question.  To begin, C# is the first programming language I have learned and I have taught myself the basics to it over the past month +.  In my app I use the minimalistic telnet library to make telnet connections and execute commands.  The problem is that I have some 2000 different clients to connect to and most are on cell connections.  When I telnet into them some response quickly with a prompt and in some rare cases they can take up to 9 seconds just to give the login prompt.

What I want to do is modify the minimalistic telnet code to wait for the login prompt portion for up to 9 seconds.

What I have tried so far is changing the predefined timeouts to 9000:

```
string s = tc.Login("root", "pass", 9000);
```

Changed the timeout inside of the telnet class to 9000 and every combination in between:

```
class Telnet
{
    TcpClient tcpSocket;
    // default timeout 9000
    int TimeOutMs = 9000;
```

I have replaced the original code:

```
if (prompt != "#" && prompt != "$" && prompt != ":")
throw new Exception("Connection failed");
```

with my own code:

```
while (prompt != "#" && prompt != "$" && prompt != ":" && delay != 19)
{
delay ++
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
if (delay = 12)
{
updateHistoryWindow(this, "Unit is taking a long time to respond");
}
if (delay = 19)
{
throw new Exception("Connection failed");
updateHistoryWindow(this, "Unit did not display a login prompt");
}
}
```

Using the While command in place of the original if command doesn't seem to work at all.  It doesn't wait for the while loop, it acts as though it times out first.

My app is currently set to 2500/2500 timeouts respectively and all of the typical connections work great.  If I change these timeout values to 9000 then the connection takes a minute or more as compared to a typical of 18 seconds.  I want to keep the connection speeds as quick as possible, wait only as long as needed for login prompt and not have a 9 second delay between sending commands to the server.  In theory a system that takes another 5 seconds to respond with a login prompt should only take 23 seconds to complete the operation (the rest of the responses are not delayed like the login response is).

- First off which timeout does what?  Is the one in my Form1 for the connection itself and the one in the telnet.cs file for delay between sending commands?
- How can I delay appropriately for the login prompt but still keep the rest of the process operating quickly.  Currently when I change the timeout variables it makes every connection take forever.
- Can I do away with the specified timeouts and use my own while loop, do I even need to do that?
- What is the Telnet.cs file doing with "oldTimeOutMs", "TimeOutMs" and"LoginTimeOutMs"

Below is my code for initializing the connection:

```
   try
    {
     int delay = 0;
     Telnet tc = new Telnet(MyGlobals.IP, 23);
     //login with user, password, using a timeout of 2500ms, and show server output
     string s = tc.Login("root", "pass", 2500);
     Console.Write(s);
     // Check server output to see if it responds
     string prompt = s.TrimEnd();
     prompt = s.Substring(prompt.Length - 1, 1);
     while (prompt != "#" && prompt != "$" && prompt != ":" && delay != 19)
     {
     delay ++
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
     if (delay = 12)
     {
     updateHistoryWindow(this, "Unit is taking a long time to respond");
     }
     if (delay = 19)
     {
     throw new Exception("Connection failed");
     updateHistoryWindow(this, "Unit did not display a login prompt");
     }
     }
     prompt = "";
     // while connected
     if (tc.IsConnected)
     { etc....
```

Here is the bulk of the telnet.cs from minimalistic telnet for reference:

```
   namespace MYApp
   {
       enum Verbs
       {
           WILL = 251,
           WONT = 252,
           DO = 253,
           DONT = 254,
           IAC = 255
       }

       enum Options
       {
           SGA = 3
       }

       class Telnet
       {
           TcpClient tcpSocket;
           // default timeout was 2500
           int TimeOutMs = 2500;

           public Telnet(string Hostname, int Port)
           { 
               tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);
           }

           public string Login(string Username, string Password, int LoginTimeOutMs)
           {
               int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
               TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
               string s = Read();
               if (s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(" "))
                   throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
               WriteLine(Username);
               s += Read();
               if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
                   throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
               WriteLine(Password);
               s += Read();
               TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
               return s;
           }
           public void WriteLine(string cmd)
           {
               Write(cmd + "\n");
           }
           public void Write(string cmd)
           {
               if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
               byte[] buf =        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF", "\0xFF\0xFF"));
        tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            ParseTelnet(sb);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
        } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
    }

    void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
        {
            int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
            switch (input)
            {
                case -1:
                    break;
                case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                    // interpret as command
                    int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                    if (inputverb == -1) break;
                    switch (inputverb)
                    {
                        case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                            //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                            sb.Append(inputverb);
                            break;
                        case (int)Verbs.DO:
                        case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                        case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                        case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                            // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                            int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                            if (inputoption == -1) break;
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                            if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA)
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL : (byte)Verbs.DO);
                            else
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT);
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    sb.Append((char)input);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help with this!

Comment: I've a NuGet package derived from minimalistic (that's been modified to work as you're requiring) at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telnet (code at https://github.com/9swampy/Telnet/) that may be able to help if you're still not sorted...

Answer (score 0):

This is a long question.  First I would look at the examples on following website.  They use Sockets and can be replaced with any class the inherits the socket class like tcpclient or tcplistener.  I would use the Asynchronous example in your case : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Here are answers to questions
1) First off which timeout does what?
Answer : Wait a fixed period of time
2) Is the one in my Form1 for the connection itself and the one in the telnet.cs file for delay between sending commands?
Answer :
a) The one in form is to indicate an error if no rfesponse
b) The one in telnet.cs to make sure entire message is received before continuing. The can be eliminated by replacing Read (asynchronous method) with an ansynchronous event in the socket listener example.

3) How can I delay appropriately for the login prompt but still keep the rest of the process operating quickly. Currently when I change the timeout variables it makes every connection take forever.
Answer : Use Asynchronous socket example

4) Can I do away with the specified timeouts and use my own while loop, do I even need to do that?
Answer : Use Asynchronous socket example

5) What is the Telnet.cs file doing with "oldTimeOutMs", "TimeOutMs" and"LoginTimeOutMs" 
Answer : Use to reset a Timer event in the form application

There is nothing wrong with using timers in this code provided it is not blocking the code from continuing and only being used to trigger an event to indicate when something didn't happen.  The timer code can be replaced with an asynchronous event rather then a synchronous wait which stops code from processing other messages.

Comment: I think this response is going to take me some time to process.  I will look at the example you provided in regards to implementing asynchronous socket. Hopefully it makes sense to me!

Comment: So I need to replace the public string Read() in the telnet.cs file with an asynchronous version of the same such as the one you linked.  Would you be willing to provide an example to help with this?  I have worked with Asynchronous commands but only a small amount.